# SetTimeout makes multiple call to a function how to avoid it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 setTimeout function which calls 2 different function , but in some case call to a function from setTimeout happens multiple times not sure how to resolve this any help would be appreciated. i use this script to find the user idle time on a webpage and i update the idle time to my DB.

```js
window.onmousemove = resetTimer('y');
window.onload = resetTimer('y');
window.onmousemove = resetTimer('y');
window.onmousedown = resetTimer('y');
window.onmouseup = resetTimer('y');
window.ontouchstart = resetTimer('y');
window.onclick = resetTimer('y');
window.onkeypress = resetTimer('y');
window.onscroll = resetTimer('y');
var t;

function resetTimer(v) {
  clearTimeout(t);
  if (v == 'y') {
    t = setTimeout(Ytimepop, 4000);
  }
  if (v == 'z') {
    t = setTimeout(Ztimepop, 5000);
  }
}

function Ytimepop() {
  // ajax code
  resetTimer('z');
}

function Ztimepop() {
  // ajax code
}
```

On window mouseover and other events i called a function which will call the resetTimer('y') and start calculating  Ytimepop timer and the function is getting called multiple times same happens for Ztimepop timer too.

Comment: `window.onmousemove = resetTimer('y');` This code gets executed immediately, in effect it is the same as `var returnValue = resetTimer('y'); window.onmousemove = returnValue;`. What you are looking for is to cancel the timer on every mousemove, so wrap it in another function that can call the function with those arguments every time: `window.onmousemove = () => resetTimer('y');`

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
var t;
window.onmouseover = function() {
  resetTimer('y');
}
function resetTimer(v) {
    clearTimeout(t);
    // --- rest of your code                     
}
```

It is not clear that you want to use `onmouseover` or `onmousemove`

Comment: This is not even correct - the function _does not get called_ every time, it gets called once when its assigned. After that `window.onmousemove` is simply set to `undefined`, the return value of `resetTimer`.

Comment: Actually i call the function in document ready as well as mouseover event

Comment: @ManoharSingh So? If you call both in this way, neither is called when you think they are - you are immediately invoking the functions, which means they get invoked when you try to set them to be called on events. When the events finally roll around, they are `undefined` and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs at this piece of code:

```
window.onmousemove = resetTimer('y');
```

Essentially, what you are doing is akin to this:

```
let returnValue = resetTimer('y'); // resetTimer executed, returns `undefined`
window.onmousemove = returnValue; // Also `undefined`
```

After this initial call, your `resetTimer` is never executed again, let alone on `mousemove`. So simply wrap it another function to call the `resetTimer`, either in the traditional way:

```
window.onmousemove = function(){ resetTimer('y'); };
```

Or with a new `arrow function`:

```
window.onmousemove = () => resetTimer('y');
```

Comment: Hi @somethinghere i still face the same issue not sure what went wrong , may be multiple time resettimer and setTimeout initialize is the cause of the issue not sure.

Comment: @ManoharSingh you might want to just look into a debounce function, to delay responses to events instead of writibg it yourself. Also, this ‘waiting for DB’ you talk about might be better of using Promises and perhaps the Fetch API. Theres also an Idle API i read about, but few browsers support it.

Comment: @somthinghere Thank you for the response, i will try the above suggested things.